# Suggest Similar references Not Available In Database

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server

I am implementing a feature in which user will enter a document with a reference.If reference already exists in database I want to show him some suggestions say:

**CC03 is not Available try CC04, CC05, CC06, CC07**
 or any other available in the sequence.

How can I implement this feature, any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create similar words by Phonetics Algorithms. there are a lot algorithms from which you create phonetics words one of them is Soundex. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_algorithm you can find detail about more algorithms in this link.

you can easily find Soundex implementation in c# on google. one link is this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1753/A-SoundEx-implementation-in-NET